# Access image in memory given starting address and size

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

So I'm trying to access jpg image data that's stored in the computer's memory, but I'm only able to access the starting address of the data and the size of the data. The pointer to the beginning of the data is an `uint8_t *` and the size of the data is an `uint32_t`.

Using `fwrite`, I can write the data to a jpg file and display it properly, so I know the data is correct and exists. How can I directly store the jpg image data in a variable? Ultimately, I want to store it in an opencv Mat too.

I'm not sure what code to show, so if you want to see a specific part of it, just ask.

Comment: If you have a pointer to it, it's already stored in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
uint8_t *JPEG;
JPEG = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * size_var);
if(JPEG) {
  memcpy(JPEG, your_pointer, size_var);
}
```

However, you do already have the data in a variable since you already have a pointer to it. :)

If you wanted to be really fancy you could build a `struct` that correctly formatted the header of a JPEG and then typecast the raw memory into the struct to better manipulate it.

Comment: malloc in C++? what about new, or even a juicy vector?

Comment: doesnt give you reason to use malloc, you can new uint8_t just fine

Comment: I don't get it. First you set `JPEG` equal to the value returned by `malloc`, even though you don't need to allocate anything. Then, if it's valid, you throw it away and replace it with some other value?!

Answer (score 2):

you know the resolution of the image? if so

to store it in an opencv Mat you can do

```
cv::Mat buf = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8U, buff_ptr);
cv::Mat img = cv::imdecode(buf, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a variable of type `uint8_t *` that contains a pointer to it, you can access it just like an array.

```
uint8_t* my_pointer;
int my_len;

for (int i = 0; i < my_len; ++i)
    cout << "The value of byte " << i
        << " of the data is " << my_pointer[i] << endl;
```